# Laravel PDF Exports: How to export data based by id

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, export, dompdf

I wanted to export the data based by id so it doesn't get all the data in the database, so example if the site is "http://127.0.0.1:8000/pengajuan/3" the "/3" is the 'submission_id' i wanted to export from, here's my code:

Controller

```
public function exportpdf()
    {
        $submissionDetail = SubmissionDetail::all();
    
        $pdf = PDF::loadview('pengajuan_detail.pdf',['submissionDetail'=>$submissionDetail]);
        return $pdf->stream();
    }
```

SubmissionDetail.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SubmissionDetail extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'submission_id', 'nama_barang', 'image_path', 'jumlah', 'harga_satuan', 'harga_total', 'keterangan',
    ];
    public function submission()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Submission');
    }

    public function negotiation()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Negotiation');
    }

    public function realization()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Realization');
    }
}
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is for `exportpdf()` function

```php
// This will convert url string to array with '/' declimiter
$url = explode('/', url()->current()); // something like [..., '127.0.0.1:8000', 'pengajuan', '3']
$id = end($url); // result is 3

// Get Specific Submission detail with "where" function
$submissionDetail = SubmissionDetail::where('submission_id', $id)->first();

// Rest is just same
$pdf = PDF::loadview('pengajuan_detail', ['submissionDetail' => $submissionDetail]);
return $pdf->stream();
```

If error occurs, it can be from your PDF template (you can post error if it happens) since you directly using PDF file as a template, not the blade file

Comment: Greetings, please accept my gratitude. I modify the code and made it simpler `public function exportpdf($id)
    {
        $submissionDetail = SubmissionDetail::all()->where('submission_id', $id);
    
        $pdf = PDF::loadview('pengajuan_detail.pdf',['submissionDetail'=>$submissionDetail]);
        return $pdf->stream();
    }`

Comment: Good to know you fix your own problem!